# Can NivoSlider support div instead of img

Tags: nivo-slider

Im a using nivo slider to use create a slideshow but i am using "div" elements instead of using "img" as Nivo Slider Demos.  But nivo apparently does not support "div" elements or support it and should i use another configuracion ?

I want to use this HTML markup for my slipder

```
<div id='background_image' class="fadein">
 <div class="imgbk" style="background-image:url(/media/2374/newbackground.jpg);"></div>
 <div class="imgbk" style="background-image:url(/media/2374/dummy_1.jpg);"></div>
 <div class="imgbk" style="background-image:url(/media/2374/dummy_2.jpg);"></div>
 <div class="imgbk" style="background-image:url(/media/2374/dummy_3.jpg);"></div>
 <div class="imgbk" style="background-image:url(/media/2374/dummy_4.jpg);"></div>
 <div class="imgbk" style="background-image:url(/media/2374/dummy_5.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From nivoslider's demo pages it supports images only. Use another slider plugin if you want HTML content. If you search for "jquery content slider" or similar you will find dozens which will most likely suit your needs.

If as in your example you're just transferring the images to inline styled backgrounds (which seems weird but perhaps for funky borders or radius or something?) you realise you can apply the same styles to the IMG tag as you can to the DIV?